# Storing Texts in a Single text when Browser is Resized in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010, css

I am learning HTML and CSS by trying to replicate a website's features and as of now I am succeeding doing it. But when I re-sized the browser(I am using Chrome), I noticed that the texts are stored to another text. I am trying to replicate the features of www.bostonglobe.com

The Sections Bar that contains News, Metro, Arts.... Insiders are being stored in section when  chrome is being restored or re-sized.

How will I do that using CSS/HTML5?

I am using ul and li tags for News, Metro, Arts.... Insiders inside a div.

Thanks.

Comment: Boston Globe's website is using what is called a Responsive Grid System (google it!). The exact one they are using is https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

Comment: Thanks redditor, I'll look for it. :)